# My program skips a bunch of code when I include multiple arrays inside the structure

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am trying to learn structures in C++. When I run my code like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct person{
    char firstName[50];
    int age;
    float gradYear;
};
int main(){
    person p1;

    cout << "Whats your FIRST name?";
    cin.get(p1.firstName, 50);
    cout << "Whats your AGE?";
    cin >> p1.age;
    cout << "Whats your GRADUATION YEAR?";
    cin >> p1.gradYear;

    cout << "Displaying Your Information . . . " << endl;
    cout << "First Name: " << p1.firstName << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << p1.age << endl;
    cout << "Graduation Year: " << p1.age << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the code works as I want it to, but when I run the code like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct person{
    char firstName[50];
    char lastName[50];
    int age;
    char branch[50];
    float gradYear;
};
int main(){
    person p1;

    cout << "Whats your FIRST name?";
    cin.get(p1.firstName, 50);
    cout << "Whats your LAST name?";
    cin.get(p1.lastName, 50);
    cout << "Whats your AGE?";
    cin >> p1.age;
    cout << "Are you Corps or Civilian?";
    cin >> p1.branch;
    cout << "Whats your GRADUATION YEAR?";
    cin >> p1.gradYear;

    cout << "Displaying Your Information . . . " << endl;
    cout << "First Name: " << p1.firstName << endl;
    cout << "Last Name: " << p1.lastName << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << p1.age << endl;
    cout << "Branch: " << p1.branch << endl;
    cout << "Graduation Year: " << p1.age << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the code outputs the information after I enter the FIRST name. Why does it do this, and how can I get it to work the second way?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `cin.get()` method inputs the first name and when you press enter the enter gets inputted into all other inputs. this is an unexpected behaviour ...

you can overcome this by writing `getch()` between the inputs.

By that I mean..

```
    cout << "Whats your FIRST name?"; 
cin.get(p1.firstName, 50); 
    getch();
    cout << "Whats your LAST name?"; 
cin.get(p1.lastName, 50);
    getch();
    cout << "Whats your AGE?"; 
    cin >> p1.age; 
    getch();
    cout << "Are you Corps or Civilian?";
    cin >> p1.branch;
    getch();
    cout << "Whats your GRADUATION YEAR?";
    cin >> p1.gradYear;
    getch();
```

Comment: what do you mean between the inputs?

Comment: What is the mac alternative for this because I code in Xcode?

Comment: for getch() you would have to include conio.h header file. and if you are using C++ 12 or higher, you can use either getchar() or cin.get()